# Hibernate Loads Entity that has already been manually set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    B classB;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classB")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    List<A> classACollection;
}
```

When I manually set the "classB" property with a valid instance of entity B, and then save the instance of entity A, hibernate will still attempt to retrieve the "classB" property from the database using a SELECT query even though I had manually loaded the "classB" property.

```
// Service Layer Code 
B classB = dao.getClassB();
A classA = new A();
classA.setClassB(classB);

// Dao function call will invoke hibernate session save() 
// this call will result in a SELECT query being made by hibernate
// to retrieve the instance of classB even though I just set it 
// in the previous line.
dao.save(classA);
```

Why does hibernate do this? And is there a way to prevent this inefficient query from occurring?

Comment: the service Layer code is it inside a transaction ?

Comment: Yes, the service layer is @Transactional

Comment: Hibernate will load the entity from the first level cache if the instance is persistent ( B classB = dao.getClassB() should be in a transactional method), if the Instance of B is detached then he will try to load it again.

Comment: I see, yeah the retrieval of classB occurs in a separate service layer call / transaction.